# Proper use of opacity with nested DIVs?

Tags: css, opacity

So I'm trying to create a lightbox like feel. I created a `#blackout` div and an `#enlargedBOX` div.

The `#blackout` div has it's opacity set to 90%, because I want the background website to show through just a bit, however i do NOT want my `#enlargedBOX` div to use that same opacity. It seems that `#blackout` forces its own opacity onto anything within itself. How can i stop that?

```
<div id="blackout">
<div id="enlargedBOX">
        <img src="" width="500" height="500" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGYvM/)

You'll see that the RED background shows through on the white `#enlargedBOX` div.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `rgba()` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGYvM/4/)

```css
#blackout {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

Comment: Yea, i just realized using opacity: affects child elements and rgba does not.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Take the `enlargedBOX` dialog div out from within the `blackout` background overlay div, and give it a higher z-index.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GGYvM/1/)**

```
#enlargedBOX {
    position:relative;
    z-index:101;
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

<div id="blackout"></div>
<div id="enlargedBOX">
    <img src="" width="500" height="500" border="0" />
</div>
```